# On Amazon EC2, using the Ruby on Rails Fedora AMI image, where is the mongrel_rail process getting launched?

Tags: amazon-ec2, fedora, ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out where the the mongrel_rails process is getting started on an Amazon EC2 box.  I am launching this instance:

**Ruby on Rails Web Starter (AMI Id: ami-bf3968fa)**

I think there is a non standard script getting run:

`/home/webuser/helloworld/restart.sh`

but I don't see any way that it is getting hit from rc3.d or rc5.d since there is no link to that script anywhere in those directories.  I can't find any instance of any call to that script in /etc at all.  Where is heck is that process getting started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer!  Writing this down so I can find this again.

This AMI image has a brain dead installation.  The rails services are not being started by the init.d scripts.  Note that both the mysqld service and the rails_mogrel are being started by crontab!??!!  Why would anyone do this?

```
more /var/spool/cron/root
```

will return:

```
# restart your mongrel server
@reboot /bin/sh /home/webuser/helloworld/restart.sh
@reboot /bin/sh /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

I edited crontab for root via:

```
crontab -e
```

and rebooted and noticed that rails was not running!